# Average of 3 IEnumerables

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I need to average 3 IEnumerable collection and create a new IEnumerable with the result as follows:

```
var result1 = GetResult1()//Returns an enumerable collection having elements 1,2,3,4

var result2 = GetResult2()//Returns an enumerable collection having elements 3,4,2,6

var result3 = GetResult3()//returns an enumerable collection having elements 2,5,1,6

//I need to create a collection which has the averages of the above results as below:

var result4 = GetResult4()//Should return 2.00,3.67,2.33,5.33.
```

- Each results will be having the same number of elements i.e result1, result2, result3 will be having the same number of elements (in this case 4, but actually it can range till 1500).
- Each element in the result corresponds to the average value of the results i.e in result4 collection the first element will be an average of 1,3,2 which corresponds to the average of the first element in result1,result2,result3 respectively and hence forth.
- The resultant collection should be having decimal places rounded to 2.

An obvious answer is to iterate through each element in the collections and create the elements in the resultant collection manually (i.e via a for loop), however I want to avoid it as the results will have close to 1500 elements in each collection and would like to do some sort of lazy evaluation using LINQ.

Please can you help me with some pointers?

Cheers,
-Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you can use `Enumerable.Zip` to good effect here:

```
var averages = result1.Zip(result2, (x, y) => x + y)
                      .Zip(result3, (xy, z) => (xy + z) / 3.0d)
                      .ToList();
```

This won't do any rounding - that would normally be more appropriate for a *formatting* step. Note that the values can only end with 0, 0.33, or 0.67 anyway, as you're only dividing by 3. Here I've used `double` but another option would be to use `decimal` - it depends on what the values really mean.

Comment: Imagine a fibonacci series with the first 1000 numbers of the series in the each collection, i.e result1,result2 and result3 each containing the series. I believe you would use a decimal for result4 then, correct?

Comment: @Mike: I don't know, to be honest. There's no "unit" there, really... it's easier to tell with concrete amounts such as "height" and "salary". Could you just return the sum, instead of dividing it by three at all? It's the same data, just scaled, after all...

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to write a method which takes a list of lists, and does the necessary work. Something like:

```
 private static IEnumerable<double> AverageOfLists(params IEnumerable<double>[] values)
 {
     var lists = values.Select(v => v.ToList()).ToArray();

     for(var i=0;i<lists[0].Count;i++)
     {
         var sum = 0.0;
         for(var j=0;j<lists.Length;j++)
         {
             sum+= lists[j][i];
         }
         yield return sum/lists.Length;
     }
 }
```

Usage would then be

```
var result4 = AverageOfLists(result1,result2,result3);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/IGOSE98291

NB: Not included rounding for the same reason @Jon mentioned; rounding is a formatting/display step.

Comment: Not that this requires all the data to be pulled into memory, when there's no real need for it. It can all be done in a streaming fashion.